# Why is not AUC or other metrics used for splitting nodes in decision trees?

Tags: decision-trees

There are common ways to split a tree in decision trees and all their variants:

- Gini Index
- Entropy
- Misclassification

Why there is not a method which uses directly AUC or accuracy (or whichever the modeler need) to split the nodes.

Is it because of common use, or there is a mathematical explanation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On accuracy:
[Why we use information gain over accuracy as splitting criterion in decision tree?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14433/why-we-use-information-gain-over-accuracy-as-splitting-criterion-in-decision-tre)

AUC has been explored; it seems to work well, but is slower:
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Learning-Decision-Trees-Using-the-Area-Under-the-Ferri-Flach/46e40f487e555277033f188778d6c5c05df8daa4
http://proceedings.mlr.press/v7/doetsch09.html